# python number arrangment loops infinitly

Tags: python

i wrote this piece of code that arranges the numbers given by the order that user applies but there is a problem with the last part where if user enter's somthing random it just infinite loop's the "else" how can i fix this?
`

```
#Taking multiple inputs from user entries
x = list(input("Enter multiple value: ").split())
print("List of numbers: ", x)

user = str(input("do you want accending or decending order? "))

while True:
    if user == "accend":
        x.sort()
        print(x)
        break
    elif user == "decend":
        x.sort(reverse=True)
        print(x)
        break
    else:
        print("are you stupid? >:( try again! ")

print("congtaz! here are you'r numbers showing in "+ user +" order")
```

`

i just dont get the logic of while in this problem

Comment: you have to move user inside the while loop

Comment: `split()` returns a list, you don't need to call `list()`.

Comment: The loop never updates `user`. So if it's not valid the first time, it will never become valid and the loop will repeat forever.

Comment: Put the input function into your while loop, the user cant try again if you have a constant that just gets checked all over again. Also, the split() function already returns a list, so no need to use the list() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason of the infinite loop is that once you enter anything besides "ascend" or "decend", it is stored in `user`, then when you enter the while, all it is doing is repeating while-else part and never let the variable `user` to change anymore. What you need is to use `input()` again in the `else` and thus let the user to change the variables content.

Comment: thanks for the help! it's working how did i forget about input